# How to filter columns in addition to summing up in sql developer?

Tags: sql, datetime, sum, case, filtering

I wrote this code to get the number of risks with different status but I don't want the result in multiple rows, I just added the `C_INSERTTIME` field in order to filter the time later. how can i get the result in one row?

```
SELECT rsk.C_INSERTTIME inserttime,
       SUM(CASE 
                WHEN rskst.c_code = 'HSE_RISK_STATUS_DRAFT' THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS drafted_risk,
       SUM(CASE 
                WHEN rskst.c_code <> 'HSE_RISK_STATUS_DRAFT' THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS analyzed_risk,
       SUM(CASE 
                WHEN rskdecsass.c_code = 'HSE_DECISION_ASSESSMENT_APPROVED' THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS approved_assessed_risks       
  FROM T_HSE_RISK rsk
       LEFT JOIN t_hse_category_element rskst ON rskst.c_id = rsk.f_category_element_id_rsk_stts
       LEFT JOIN t_hse_category_element rskdecsass ON rskdecsass.c_id = rsk.F_CTGRY_ELMNT_ID_DCSN_ASSSSMNT 
WHERE rsk.C_INSERTTIME >= TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY rsk.C_INSERTTIME
```

Comment: What does this mean?  "in order to filter the time later".  Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `GROUP BY` and use aggregation on `C_inserttime` as follows:

```
SELECT min(rsk.C_INSERTTIME) inserttime, -- or max
       SUM(CASE 
                WHEN rskst.c_code = 'HSE_RISK_STATUS_DRAFT' THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS drafted_risk,
       SUM(CASE 
                WHEN rskst.c_code <> 'HSE_RISK_STATUS_DRAFT' THEN 1
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS analyzed_risk,
       SUM(CASE 
                WHEN rskdecsass.c_code = 'HSE_DECISION_ASSESSMENT_APPROVED' THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS approved_assessed_risks       
  FROM T_HSE_RISK rsk
       LEFT JOIN t_hse_category_element rskst ON rskst.c_id = rsk.f_category_element_id_rsk_stts
       LEFT JOIN t_hse_category_element rskdecsass ON rskdecsass.c_id = rsk.F_CTGRY_ELMNT_ID_DCSN_ASSSSMNT 
WHERE rsk.C_INSERTTIME >= TIMESTAMP '2000-01-01 00:00:00'
-- GROUP BY rsk.C_INSERTTIME -- removed this
```